# Jquery selector on multiline rich text field

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint

I have added the following HTML on my sharepoint NewForm page to create a temporary multi line rich text field.

```
<div class="ms-inputBox ms-inputBoxActive" id="NewLog2" title="NewLog3">
    <div id="NewLog5" title="NewLog" name="NewLog5" role="textbox" style="overflow: auto; min-height: 168px; max-height: 336px;" contenteditable="true" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-multiline="true" RteDirty="false">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have unsuccessfully tried all the following selectors to retrieve the entered value

```
   var AddLog = $("textarea[Title='NewLog']").val();alert(AddLog);
   var AddLog = $("textarea[Title='NewLog']").text();alert(AddLog);
   var AddLog = $("input[Title='NewLog']").val();alert(AddLog);
   var AddLog = $("input[Title='NewLog']").text();alert(AddLog);
```

Is the selector wrong or the html?

Comment: entered value where? this should be inside the input or keypress event

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you want to read the rich text on a button click, so you can try this:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
   alert($('#NewLog5').html());
});
```

Comment: No, actually on a presaveaction. The javascript reads back through screen elements and processes them before the save. I added in the code: var x = $('#NewLog5').html();alert(x); the alert just came back with 'undefined'

Comment: I have not worked on Sharepoint exactly but can you right click the form > open inspector > inspect the div and see if the text is there? if it is, maybe you can run this selector in the console and see what op it gives.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hints! The following both worked.

```
var x = $('#NewLog').html();alert(x);
var x = $('#NewLog').text();alert(x);
```

Worked in conjunction with the HTML

```
<div class="ms-inputBox ms-inputBoxActive">
    <div id="NewLog" role="textbox" style="overflow: auto; min-height: 168px; max-height: 336px;" contenteditable="true" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-multiline="true" RteDirty="false">
    </div>
</div>
```

Not sure why the previous suggested test didn't work.